# ember-data render belongsTo attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, belongs-to

ember-cli 0.2.3; ember-data 1.0.0-beta.15

I'm struggling to figure out how to display attributes for a belongsTo object inside a template. I've found a few other similar questions here but they're either out of date or don't provide a solution.

User model:

    `export default DS.Model.extend({
        ...
        agency  : DS.belongsTo("agency"),
    });`

Agency model:

    `var Agency = DS.Model.extend({
        ...
        users: DS.hasMany("user"),
    });`

User serializer:

    `export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
        attrs: {
            agencies: {
                embedded: "always"
            }
        }
    });`

ApplicationSerializer:

    `export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({});`

The JSON (for index route) looks like so:

    `{
        "users": [
          {
                "id"       : "1",
                "name"     : "...",
                "agency_id": "6",
                "agencies" : [
              {
                        "id"  : "6",
                        "name": "...",
                ...
              }
            ]
          },
          ...
        ]
    }`

Although Ember isn't complaining, i'm not even sure that the data is coming in correctly because the documentation for EmbeddedRecordsMixin shows a belongsTo example as:

    `{
      "post": {
        "id": "1"
        "title": "Rails is omakase",
        "author": {
          "id": "2"
          "name": "dhh"
        }
      }
    }`

In any case, i can see that the agency data is included, although it seems that it has to be as an array, though there is only ever a single one per user. I haven't been able to find a complete explanation of precisely what format is expected.

However, the main thing is: How the heck do i display the agency name in a template?

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't work:

    `{{#each user in model}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.get('agencies').firstObject().get("name")}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}`

**UPDATE:** 
I'd modified the data to look like this:

    `{
        "users": [
          {
                "id"       : "1",
                "name"     : "...",
                "agency_id": "6",
                "agency" : [
              {
                        "id"  : "6",
                        "name": "...",
                ...
              }
            ]
          },
          ...
        ]
    }`

... and updated the model to have agency: DS.belongsTo("agency") and serializer as attrs: {agency: {embedded: "always"}} but that threw an error. The solution was to also remove agency_id from the data.

Comment: firstObject is property of Ember.Enumerable which DS.ManyArray uses, not a function. In your template try: user.agencies.firstObject.name Also after the model loads with its embeded models, check ember inspector -> data and verify that your model got loaded correctly

Comment: Your json is wrong, it should be `{ users: [ { agency : {} }]} `

Comment: and you should access it using `user.agency.name`

Comment: @xoma user.agencies.firstObject.name yields nothing. And i had checked the inspector but forgot to mention it. Under belongsTo it says Agency is null.

Comment: @Kingpin2k What i thought as well. I'm using a CakePHP plugin to serialize for Ember. It makes a point of pluralizing the model name, as well as ensuring there's an array. I've opened an issue with the authors asking for clarification on their motives.

Comment: @Kingpin2k  I tried disabling that functionality (of mentioned Cake plugin) and edited the serializer to use "agency" to get suggested format but also the following error:

Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `agency` relationship instead it found an object. ... If this is an embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and specify the `agency` property in your serializer's attrs object.

However, i am already using EmbeddedRecordsMixin. I figure i'm still missing something else that needs changing.

Comment: Your attr should be agency as well,  `attrs: { agency: { embedded: "always" } }`

Comment: Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jozekiwinu/1/edit

Comment: I had already edited the serializer after modifying the data format. After taking a look at your jsbin, though, i realised that one difference was that i still had agency_id. For some reason that was causing an error. I'll edit my question. If you post your last comment as an answer i'll mark it as solved as it was that that gave me the idea.